# How to change the "from" header while sending an email from cpanel?

Tags: php, email, gmail

I'm trying to send email to my gmail account from my website using mail() function. This is working fine but the problem is, when I receive the mail in my gmail account inbox ( not in spam ), there is a '?' mark instead of a regular blank profile picture. When I hover over the '?' mark, a message pops up saying,"Gmail couldn't verify that mywebsite.com actually sent this message (and not a spammer)". I have added two pictures of this issue. I contacted to my hosting provider and they told me that it was a script related issue. They analyzed the file which I got by clicking on "Show original" in my gmail inbox. They said that, the problem occurred because the 'from' email address that gmail got was "cpanel-username@server-hostname.com" instead of "myemail@website.com". I have to replace "cpanel-username@server-hostname.com" with "myemail@website.com". I tried a lot but was unable to change the "from" header. My code is something like this

```
$Email = "myemail@gmail.com";
$message = "Hello!!";
$headers = "From: Mywebsite <noreply@mywebsite.com>";

$sentmail = mail("$Email",'Something Important',"$message",$headers);
```

Note that, "noreply@mywebsite.com" is a real email address which I created in my cpanel. I also tried phpmailer to solve this issue but I did not succeed. My phpmailer code is like this

```
require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isMail();    // I also tried $mail->isSMTP(), but it does not work. Just keeps loading the page but never completes.
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'noreply@mywebsite.com';
$mail->Password = '****************';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 365;

$mail->setFrom('noreply@mywebsite.com', 'Mywebsite');
$mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Something Important';
$mail->Body    = 'Hello!!';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

But this also does not solve my problem. The from header is still "cpanel-username@server-hostname.com" when the mail is received in gmail. Please someone help me with this issue. [image]

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Later I used PHPmailer which solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

you can add the -f user@domain.tld to a mail.force_extra_parameters line in your php.ini. 
See the solution provided here. It helped me.
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/email-sent-as-username-hostname.601655/